# How to server validate via menuItemClick

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, server-side

I am newbie to .Net and I got a quick question. In my web form I have 3 textboxes that should be validated on menuItemClick in the server side. How that can be achieved. I saw that each textbox has onValidation attribute, but when this validation is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the validation process is clear to me. For a server side validation the following process should be completed. First we create validators and map them to the specific controls. After that we set CausesValidation property of the controls to true. Then on every postback (in my case OnClick event) we check if the Page.IsValid is == to true.

Answer (score 0):

In web applications, we have 2 types of validations.

1- Server-side validations
2- Client-side validations

Client-side validations are performed usually using java script by the browser itself. Since it is deployed on client's computer, it can be changed or even disabled. They just help you to validate inputs more easily before anything sent to the server.

Server-side validations are primary validations which you SHOULD always perform on the server side to validate and sanitize the input values before any operation. This can't be changed by the clients because it is located on the server side and in order to change them, a user needs to have access to assemblies created on the server.

What you are saying, if I understood correctly, is a client-side validation which means whenever you want to post your form back to server, validations will be performed on the client side, browser.

Comment: hmm not exactly on every postback. I have 3 states in my program(they are stored in a ViewState element) : Browsing, Editing and Inserting. When Browsing (navigating trough the db with first,next,previous,last) I actually don't need any validation. However when I want to edit or insert a new item, I am entering in a new state, and just before completing the operation ( via pressing save menu item) an alert event is fired. I want to make the validation before that alert.